# Joomla mobile menu conflicts

Tags: jquery, mobile, joomla

I am working on Joomla website. This is the [link](http://www.konarknirman.com/index.php) to the website. This website with two menus is working fine on the desktop size screen but when viewed on smartphone, say, iphone 5 
it shows eight drop down menus instead of two. 
This is the image when [this link](http://www.konarknirman.com/index.php/konark-gardens) is viewed  on iphone: 
 [image]. 
 
The page opens fine on mobile device when there is only one menu. I can not see any kind of js conflict either. From where should I start diagnosing the issue? 
 Thanks. 
**EDIT:** There are only two menu modules that too only on the inside links one of which is posted here. I have superfish menu template code posted here:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_menu
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters, Inc. 
All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Note. It is important to remove spaces between elements.
$layouttype = $params->get('layouttype');
switch ($layouttype) {
case 'hor':
    $layout_class = "";
    break;
    case 'vert':
    $layout_class = "sf-vertical";
    break;
    case 'nav':
    $layout_class = "sf-navbar";
    break;  
default:
    $layout_class = "";
    break;
}
?>

<ul class="sf-menu <?php echo $class_sfx;?> <?php echo $layout_class; ?>"<?php
$tag = '';
if ($params->get('tag_id')!=NULL) {
    $tag = $params->get('tag_id').'';
    echo ' id="'.$tag.'"';
}
?>>

<?php
foreach ($list as $i => &$item) :
$class = 'item-'.$item->id;
if ($item->id == $active_id) {
    $class .= ' current';
}

if (in_array($item->id, $path)) {
    $class .= ' active';
}
elseif ($item->type == 'alias') {
    $aliasToId = $item->params->get('aliasoptions');
    if (count($path) > 0 && $aliasToId == $path[count($path)-1]) {
        $class .= ' active';
    }
    elseif (in_array($aliasToId, $path)) {
        $class .= ' alias-parent-active';
    }
}

if ($item->deeper) {
    $class .= ' deeper';
}

if ($item->parent) {
    $class .= ' parent';
}

if (!empty($class)) {
    $class = ' class="'.trim($class) .'"';
}

echo '<li'.$class.'>';

// Render the menu item.
switch ($item->type) :
    case 'separator':
    case 'url':
    case 'component':
        require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_superfish_menu', 'default_'.$item->type);
        break;

    default:
        require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_superfish_menu', 'default_url');
        break;
endswitch;

// The next item is deeper.
if ($item->deeper) {
    echo '<ul>';
}
// The next item is shallower.
elseif ($item->shallower) {
    echo '</li>';
    echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
}
// The next item is on the same level.
else {
    echo '</li>';
}
endforeach;
?></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
// initialise plugins
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('ul.sf-menu')
        <?php if($params->get('supersubs')): ?> 
            .supersubs({
                minWidth:    12,   // minimum width of sub-menus in em units
                maxWidth:    27,   // maximum width of sub-menus in em units
                extraWidth:  1     // extra width can ensure lines don't sometimes turn over
                             // due to slight rounding differences and font-family
            })
    <?php endif; ?> 
    .superfish({
        hoverClass:    'sfHover',         
    pathClass:     'overideThisToUse',
    pathLevels:    1,    
    delay:         <?php echo $params->get('sf-delay'); ?>, 
    animation:     {<?php echo $params->get('sf-animation'); ?>}, 
    speed:         '<?php echo $params->get("sf-speed"); ?>',   
    speedOut:      '<?php echo $params->get("sf-speed-out"); ?>',   
    autoArrows:    false, 
    disableHI:     false, 
    useClick:      <?php echo $params->get('useClick'); ?>,
    easing:        "<?php echo $params->get('easing'); ?>",
    onInit:        function(){},
    onBeforeShow:  function(){},
    onShow:        function(){},
    onHide:        function(){},
    onIdle:        function(){}
    });
});

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.sf-menu').mobileMenu({
        defaultText: '<?php echo $params->get('defaultText'); ?>',
        className: '<?php echo $params->get('className'); ?>',
        subMenuClass: '<?php echo $params->get('subMenuClass'); ?>'
    });
})

jQuery(function(){
    var ismobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i)
    if(ismobile){
        jQuery('.sf-menu').sftouchscreen({});
    }
})
```

**One more edit to include jquery.mobilemenu.js :**

```
(function($){
$.fn.mobileMenu = function(options) {

var defaults = {
        defaultText: 'Navigate to...',
        className: 'select-menu',
        subMenuClass: 'sub-menu',
        subMenuDash: '&ndash;'
    },
    settings = $.extend( defaults, options ),
    el = $(this);

this.each(function(){
    // ad class to submenu list
    el.find('ul').addClass(settings.subMenuClass);

    // Create base menu
    $('<select />',{
        'class' : settings.className
    }).insertAfter( el );

    // Create default option
    $('<option />', {
        "value"     : '#',
        "text"      : settings.defaultText
    }).appendTo( '.' + settings.className );

    // Create select option from menu
    el.find('a, .separator').each(function(){
        var $this   = $(this),
                optText = '' + $this.text(),
                optSub  = $this.parents( '.' + settings.subMenuClass ),
                len         = optSub.length,
                dash;

        // if menu has sub menu
        if( $this.parents('ul').hasClass( settings.subMenuClass ) ) {
            dash = Array( len+1 ).join( settings.subMenuDash );
            optText = dash + optText;
        }

        if (!$this.hasClass('separator')) {

        // Now build menu and append it
        $('<option />', {
            "value" : this.href,
            "html"  : optText,
            "selected" : (this.href == window.location.href)
        }).appendTo( '.' + settings.className );

        } else {
            $('<option />', {
            "value" : '#',
            "html"  : optText
        }).appendTo( '.' + settings.className );
        }

    }); // End el.find('a').each



    // Change event on select element
    $('.' + settings.className).change(function(){
        var locations = $(this).val();
        if( locations !== '#' ) {
            window.location.href = $(this).val();
        };
    });

}); // End this.each

return this;

};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all- this view can be achieved not only on iphone- but on desktop too if you resize browser window to size that small enough.
If you'll look at you page's source code in menu sections - you'll notice something like this:

```
<ul class="sf-menu sf-vertical">...<ul>
<script>    
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.sf-menu').mobileMenu({
    defaultText: 'Navigate to...',
    className: 'select-menu',
    subMenuClass: 'sub-menu'
    });
  })
</script>
```

This code is under EVERY menu (you have two) - so basically script here is looking for element with **sf-menu** class and make moile select menu from it.
Simple maths - you have two menus, and in **every** menu you have this code - so code looks **twice**  through your code instead of single one.
Solution: 
1. You need to override Joomla superfish menu module code, with your own - just delete from there ..., good article [here](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).
2. You need to add code from previous step ... to either your template file or in the end of your template JS file.

Comment: I have posted the menu template code here but I really don't know where to look at in the code...Can it not be something to do with the mobile javascript file?

Comment: It's definetely JS/ jQuery problem- (you can turn off JS in your browser and see yourself (this menus all gone when you resize browser window)). have you changed any base js files (or any js-plugins)?

Comment: No, changed nothing in the JS files. But, I do think that there is some issue with the functioning of this file. When I turn off the second menu module from the Joomla, the first menu module displays perfectly fine. Even on the home page it is working without any problem. I think there is some extra code to be added in the JS file but I really do not know what and where.

Comment: Sorry for such waiting, mate. been in hospital lately... You need to copy site to your local machine and try to search (select-menu)   (without brackets) through all files with your local OS search engine, tell me, please which js files your search program'll find. I'll try to help you to find what's wrong with code.

Comment: I know it is so long but I am yet to find the solution. As asked by you, jquery.mobilemenu.js is the file in which "select-menu" comes once. Shall I also post the code in this file?

Comment: Post it somewhere (jsfiddle, for example) and copy link here.

Comment: I have included the menu script code in the post above. Please have a look and help me.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for pointing out the code. However, I am not good with JS or php. I just wish to have script called out once and both the menus displayed correctly. Please help me with this. Thanks.